# Is hydrothorax considered as edema?

Tags: terminology, edema

In _Robbins Basic Pathology 9<sup>th</sup> ed., edema is defined as

> [E]dema is an accumulation of interstitial fluid within tissues. Extravascular fluid can also 
>   collect in body cavities such as the pleural cavity (hydrothorax), the pericardial cavity (hydropericardium), or the peritoneal cavity (hydroperitoneum, or ascites).

Though hydrothorax is mentioned here in relation to edema, it is not mentioned explicitly whether it is actually a subtype of edema or not. I also looked into multiple sources for edema definition; “accumulation of fluid in the interstitum”; interstitium refers to the tiny spaces between cells which is not the case for hydrothorax since pleural cavity is not interstitium (right?). So is hydrothorax considered as a subtype of edema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to various **dictionaries,** edema includes the accumulation of the fluid in the cells, between the cells (interstitial space) and in the body cavities, so, yes, hydrothorax could be considered a subtype of edema.

[TheFreeDictionary](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/edema):

> edema the accumulation of excess fluid in a fluid compartment.
>   Formerly called dropsy and hydrops. This accumulation can occur in the
>   cells (cellular edema), in the intercellular spaces within tissues
>   (interstitial edema), or in potential spaces within the body. Edema
>   may also be classified by location, such as pulmonary edema or brain
>   edema; types found in certain locations have specific names, such as
>   ascites (peritoneal cavity), hydrothorax (pleural cavity), or
>   hydropericardium (pericardial sac).

[Merriam-Webster:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/edema)

> Edema - an abnormal infiltration and excess accumulation of serous
>   fluid in connective tissue or in a serous cavity

But, in a real world, a doctor will not likely **use** the term edema for fluid in a body cavity.

The term *lung edema* is exclusively used for the fluid in the lung tissue (parenchyma) and the term *hydrtothorax* or *pleural effusion* for the fluid in the pleural space. In this case, calling hydrothorax edema would be totally confusing, even if it may be formally correct.

Comment: That’s how i used to think about it until i read about it in Robbins’ pathology which confused me and on Wikipedia “Edema, also spelled oedema or œdema, is an abnormal accumulation of fluid in the interstitium, located beneath the skin **and in the cavities of the body**, which can cause severe pain” which made me even more confused. Do you have any source to support the information given? just to relieve my doubt :)

Comment: I had to completely rewrite my answer. It is a clash between the formal definition and practical use.